# WPF can't find my new class at Design Time

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

I went and added a new class to one of my projects.  It is a visual control.

I went to use the new control in a different project.  When I did that I got this error at design time:

```
XamlParseException: Type reference cannot find type named 
           '{clr-namespace:MyControlsProject;assembly=MyControlsProject}ButtonPop'.
```

But I open the reference with object explorer and the ButtonPop class is there.  Similarly if I open the MyControllsProject.dll with DotPeek, the class is there.

I know it is specific to my new class because I tried using an existing one from that same project and it all works fine.

I know the reference is there also because this works fine at run time.

**Any ideas why I would get his design time error?**

Comment: Can you show us the xaml?

Comment: Did you add xmlns of the dll used from other proj in your Xaml??

Comment: @BrianGradin. I can, but the one that works has the same syntax as the one that does not...  And it is a lot of xaml...

Comment: @Vaccano what is "ButtonPop" in the error. Have you added it that to your xaml namespace declaration?

Comment: @Akansha that is the new visual control I added. And yes I did add the namespace. And I checked it by using a different visual control that is in the same namespace. (It worked flawlessly)

Comment: @Vaccano can you show the namespace initializations and the place where ButtonPop is used in your Xaml? No need to add full code

Comment: @Akansha I can, but I will have to do it tomorrow (I don't have the code with me).

Comment: @Akansha - So... Turns out restarting Visual Studio fixed it.  I hate how temperamental Design Time is...  If you want to post an answer saying to restart visual studio I will accept it.

Comment: @Vaccano Its ok Vaccano.. Solving the issue is more important.. :)